# data:application/PDF - 'Unable to Load PDF' error. Can someone help as soon as possible

Tags: visualforce

**VF CONTROLLER CLASS**

```
function invoiceCall(orderid){
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.cc_ccr_ctrl_OrderHistory.fetchQueryParameters}',
            orderid,
            function(result, event){
            //response from mulesoft connection
            if(result[0]=='true')
                window.open('data:application/PDF;base64,'+ escape(result[1]),'', 'height=650,width=840');
```

**APEX CLASS**

```
string queryParameter ='?outletId='+ outletId +'&invoiceNumber=' + invoiceNum + '&invoiceDate=' + orderDate ;
         system.debug('--------------> invoice pdf'+queryParameter);
         //making call to GET rest service
         HttpResponse res = cc_ccr_svc_RESTService.get('getInvoice', queryParameter);

         // checking the response of GET restservice call
         if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
           //success response
                     system.debug('--------------> invoice pdf'+res.getBodyAsBlob());
           blob body = res.getBodyAsBlob();
             system.debug('--------------> invoice pdf'+body);
           pdf=EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(body);
             system.debug('--------------> invoice pdf'+pdf);
           flag='true';
           listReturn.add(flag);
           listReturn.add(pdf);
         }
```

In the above class, I am getting .TIFF through middleware into salesforce, convert it into PDF format to display using window.open function. But I am getting error while opening the PDF as "Unable to Load PDF".

If I change the data:application/PDF to data:application/IMG, able to download the image in chrome and see the copy but not working in IE.

Can someone help!!

Comment: are you trying to open a .TIFF as though it were a .PDF? You mention "... I am getting .TIFF through middleware..." ok, noted. Where and how are you converting that to .PDF?

Comment: I am getting it in a .tiff format (array) and using blob to convert it into a PDF.system.debug('--------------> invoice pdf'+res.getBodyAsBlob());
           blob body = res.getBodyAsBlob();
             system.debug('--------------> invoice pdf'+body);
           pdf=EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(body);

Comment: window.open('data:application/PDF;base64,'

Comment: @kiranchimmiri  See my answer. It doesn't work that way. That's like importing something that's "red" and expecting it to change colors simply by calling it "blue" when you display it.

Comment: @crmprogdev, where do you want me to check your answer, can you please send me in example code if you have some thing on this

Comment: Look below these comments and you'll see a new post.

Comment: thank you for the response, @ crmprogdev, I actually have no other option other than to get a .tiff image as it is coming from a legacy system and the business did not want to change it. So, can you let me know on how can I change the blob array into pdf in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getting .TIFF through middleware into salesforce, convert it into PDF format to display using window.open function.

From what I see of your code, your rest service is simply bringing in a blob and making the assumption that it's a PDF. If it's actually a TIFF, that would explain why you're not able to display it. The two have completely different file formats. You can't simply take a base64encoded blob and decide to call it a PDF when you decode it.

You did the correct thing in changing to `data:application/IMG`. I suspect the issue with IE is one of a couple different possibilities related to the fact it's a TIFF. There are a variety of TIFF file formats out there, some are CCIT4 TIFFs (used for fax images), some are interlaced, some use LZW file compression (there's also RLE compression in older files), some will also use transparency layers/channels (including multiple ones), and you'll encounter various combinations of the above.

Not every program will know how to open all the different varieties of TIFFs. TIFF files aren't commonly used for the internet and tend to require a download, then opening in a different application. Most browsers traditionally haven't supported the TIFF file format unless through a plug-in of some kind along with a file association as the default viewer on the machine.

IE is one of those programs. I suspect that's at the root of the issue you're encountering the TIFF not displaying. I'm actually a bit surprised it displayed for you in Chrome. I hadn't realized it would displayed them, but then I always associate them with an image editor. The primary raster image formats used for displaying non vector images on the internet are bmp, jpg, gif and png. There are a few other lesser known ones that tend to be part of Adobe Flash Player, QuickTime and other media players. I highly recommend you find a different file format for these images if at all possible, preferably one of the ones I've listed above.

Comment: thank you for the response, @ crmprogdev, I actually have no other option other than to get a .tiff image as it is coming from a legacy system and the business did not want to change it. So, can you let me know on how can I change the blob array into pdf in the controller

Comment: You simply cannot change it to a PDF in the controller. You'd have to send the TIFF to a 3rd party service to have them convert it for you before import into Salesforce. The two file formats are completely different. PDFs save images internally as JPGs and then have a "wrapper" of sorts around them that you can't recreate with Apex.

Comment: So, if i understand this correctly, you want me to get the tiff to pdf conversion in mulesoft itself and then get the jpeg into salesforce as similar to a blob and use it for the display purposes??

Comment: Yes, you'd need to first send it to a site that has tool like the one from http://www.spurdoc.com/ or to Salesforce, then out and back before you could display it. Alternatively, you could send the TIFF to some site that converts it to a PNG or JPG for you. The former isn't as lossy in quality as the latter might be. There are sites you can find that will do the conversion for you. Security may be an issue of course that you'll need to contend with.

Comment: Okay, will try this options and would get back and appreciate your inputs

Comment: I know I'm coming back after 16hr gap, but just one question before going for the solution. Is there a way I can just directly display a .TIFF in salesforce without any issues on any of the browsers. Now, I do understand (from above answer of your's) tiff can have many formats and so may act differently basing on the browser as well as versions of the browser. But my question or just looking for an easy solution where I can just display the tiff instead of converting it to pdf...

Comment: part 2 of my question is whether mulesoft can convert the tiff image to pdf and send me an blob array so that I can just display the pdf directly without changing the code any where in salesforce. But then if this is an option, I would have to speak with my mulesoft resource to research on how to convert tiff to pdf in mulesoft script. If you can let me know which option is better, will try to proceed with that. Thank you.

Comment: I doubt that Mulesoft alone can do this for you. This involves an integration with a call to 3rd party service that you'll need to work out with your integration vendor. Ideally, it would be best to have the file converted by the 3rd party service before it comes into Salesforce. That's about all I can advise you.

Comment: Hello crmprogdev, Now after considering your inputs, I was able to approach Mulesoft team and make them do the conversion. But the resolution they provided is little different. They have converted the array they receive into PDF, stored it in their local system and then pass the same URL to us which without changing any code at our end was able to display PDF directly in chrome browser. But again problem with the IE browser. The issue with IE is the character limit they have which is cutting down the url and so is unable to display the image. Can you suggest any alternative to beat IE on this

Comment: Sounds like something you'll want to post on StackOverflow since it's an IE issue which isn't something that's specific to Salesforce or on topic for this Forum. You may also want to be aware that SF will end official support for IE 11 in Jan 2017.

Comment: My intention is to purely get a solution for the issue using SF. I suppose the alternative would be for mulesoft to pass in multiple parameters (subdivide the array) and in SF I can concatenate them back.